# Don't know how to use tmux key bindings in OS X: C-b has no effect

Tags: macports, tmux

I'm using tmux window manager with OS X's terminal. I'd like to be able to use the key bindings to switch between tmux panes or split them instead of having to type out 'tmux select-pane' or 'tmux split-window' every single time. However, pressing CTRL and b together, which according to the man page is the default key binding, has no effect.

For example, the man page says I should be able to type CTRL and b (or, as it puts it, C-b) along with " to split the window. Pressing these keys together does nothing. None of the key bindings produce any effect in tmux.

I tried googling the issue and got back lots of results telling me to edit my ~/.tmux.conf file, but I don't have this file at all. It doesn't exist and was not created when I installed tmux using MacPorts, thus I cannot edit it to change the key bindings.

I can't find anyone who has had a similar problem, that of the key bindings not producing any effect at all. What am I doing wrong? Does the Macbook Pro keyboard simply not support key bindings? I'd appreciate it if someone could shed light on what my problem is.

Comment: I don't know much about the question but it would be helpful to add some more **relevant** tags to your question to increase visibility. It'll increase your chance of getting an answer

Comment: Are you releasing Control and `b` before pressing `"`? The sequence `C-b "` describes two “key presses” there: `b` with Control held down, and then (separately) `"` without any modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Do simple commands work? Like C-b , to rename the window? If not maybe try using [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home)?